# ErrorDocument 403 Not Working For Subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a structure like this on a shared host:

```
~/above_public_html/public_html/directory_i_want_forbidden
```

I have an `~/above_public_html/.htaccess` with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

When I navigate to a file or folder that doesn't exist, I get the 404.html popping up, no problems.

When I navigate to a subfolder or file that exists but has `chmod 700` permissions (including the `directory_i_want_forbidden`), I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /directory_i_want_forbidden on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at www.mydomain.com Port 80
```

What do I need to do in order to make the `ErrorDocument 403 /403.html` work correctly?

Comment: By the error it seems access to `403.html` is also forbidden. Check chmod setting for that file.

Comment: Would it be looking for 403.html in the `~/above_public_html/public_html/directory_i_want_forbidden` directory?

Comment: Nope. I modified the .htaccess file to `ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mysite.com/403.html` and still getting the same error! What is going on?

Comment: Yeah.. didn't use the code ticks so it cut off the `http://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was screwy with the .htaccess or httpd.conf upstream.  I had no control over it since I was on shared hosting.  I have since started my own Amazon EC2 server-instance and everything is working as it should.